# Buidling Qt5 & QtQuick 2 application with GNU Make

Tags: c++, makefile, qt5, qtquick2

I am trying to build a very basic Qt5 application that uses QtQuick 2 as UI-Language and is build using a GNU Makefile. That means, that I don't want to use javascript, but load the QML layout and specify signals and slots in C++. However, here are my questions:

1. What's the best way to load a QML layout and access its' elements?
2. How do I build such an application directly with GNU Make instead of using qmake to generate a Makefile?

Please find my first attempts below:

**qml/main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

**src/main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

  return app.exec();
}
```

**Makefile**

```
CC          = /usr/bin/g++
MOC         = moc-qt5
CFLAGS      = -Wall -pedantic -std=c++0x -D_REENTRANT \
                            -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED
TARGET        = yarott
INCPATH         = -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/qt -I/usr/include/qt/QtGui \
                            -I/usr/include/qt/QtCore -I/usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++
LDFLAGS     = -L/usr/lib -lsqlite3 -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread
SRCPATH         = ./src
BINPATH         = ./bin

DEFINES         = $(shell find $(SRCPATH) -type f -name '*.h')
SOURCES         = $(shell find $(SRCPATH) -type f -name '*.cpp')
OBJECTS         := $(patsubst $(SRCPATH)/%.cpp, $(BINPATH)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
MOC_SOURCES := $(patsubst $(SRCPATH)/%.cpp, $(SRCPATH)/moc_%.cpp, $(SOURCES))
MOC_OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(BINPATH)/%.o, $(BINPATH)/moc_%.o, $(OBJECTS))

SOURCES += $(MOC_SOURCES)
OBJECTS += $(MOC_OBJECTS)

all: bin $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BINPATH)/$(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) $(INCPATH)

$(BINPATH)/%.o: $(SRCPATH)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p "$(@D)"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(SRCPATH)/moc_%.cpp: $(SRCPATH)/%.h
    $(MOC) $(DEFINES) $(INCPATH) $< -o $@

# Generate cc from h via Qt's Meta Object Compiler
# $(SRCPATH)/%.moc.cc: $(SRCPATH)/%.h
#   $(MOC) $(INCPATH) $< -o $@

# Create bin folder
bin:
    mkdir $(BINPATH)

# Remove bin folder
clean:
    rm -r $(BINPATH)
```

Comment: I don't know on a make project, but on a CMake QML app, moc files are generated as moc_classname.cpp, then compiled. I'm a noob concerning makefile, but it seems that you are missing that.

Comment: I've seen that you edited your post, but I still don't know what is your problem. Does you program compile ? Do you have any errors messages ?

Comment: My program does compile now, however I am not sure if everything is correct. I will post a complete answer as soon as I fixed the last issues.

Comment: Did you have an answer yet? was looking for a way to include qml to gnu makefile and stumbled upon yours.